# Search for a name in a list and display all matches

Tags: java, collections

```
case 4: if(studentInfo.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("No student record exists!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the student you want to search for: ")
                    searchName = sc2.next();

                    for(Student stu : studentInfo)
                    {
                       if(stu.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchName))
                        {
                           System.out.println("Match found: "+stu);

                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            System.out.println("No match found for the given name!");
                        }
                        break;
                     }
        }
        break;
```

This is my case block in which I'm taking a String from the user, which will be a name, and search if the List contains that name(initially records are added in previous case blocks). I want to display all those names that matches the one given by the user. 
For example: If the list has 2 records with the name John, I want to display both the records. Can someone guide me what I've got to modify in the above code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove the break; with in the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove else statement from for each loop and no need of break statement.

Here is code:

```
case 4: if(studentInfo.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("No student record exists!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the student you want to search for: ")
                    searchName = sc2.next();
                    int i = 0;

                    for(Student stu : studentInfo)
                    {
                       if(stu.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchName))
                        {
                           System.out.println("Match found: "+stu);
                           i++;

                        }
                     }
                     if(i == 0)
                         System.out.println("No Match found");
        }
        break;
```

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to iterate through the entire list. You need to remove the `break;` statement from inside your `for` loop. With this `break` statement, whenever there is match for the given `student name`, its breaking out the for loop. Its not searching through the rest of the list.

Comment: I had misplaced the `break` statement! It should've been placed after the `println` statement inside the `else` block. My bad!

Comment: actually you don't need to use the `break` statement inside your `for` loop. declare a `boolean` variable before your `for` loop: `boolean nameFound=false`. Now inside your `if block` set the boolean value to true:`nameFound=true;`(which means it has found a matching name) and let the `for` loop iterate till the last element in the list. After the `for` loop, check the value of `nameFound` variable.If it is still `false`, print `No match found`: `if(!nameFound){ syso("no name found");` .Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
       for(Student stu : studentInfo)
       {        
         if(stu.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchName))
             result = result.append(stu.getName()+ " ");  
        }
       System.out.println(result.toString());
```